# Use logged signal in Matlab Level-2 S-function (in Simulink)

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

Is it possible to use logged signals within Matlab Level-2 S-functions?
I need an S-function to run only every 5 s, so that that could be its rate. However, if I use the S-function to log the data, I need to call it at every time step and that slows down the code considerably. Is it possible to use logged signals within the Matlab Level-2 S-function instead?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you buffer the data before feeding to the s-function?

Comment: I guess I can try, but I was wondering if you can access the logged signal from within the Simulink simulation (i.e. before its completion). Thanks!